Installing Alpine Linux using Fastboot
I have a Lenovo TAB 10 (TB-X103F) with TWRP installed, but no OS.
I am attempting to install alpine linux but to my knowledge, the tablet is unable to boot from EFI, so im confused on what to do next as i cant find any bootloader that will work.
I dont know too much about how bootloaders work so any help is appreciated

Genuine OS can't be installed on Android systems. You need a custom ROM specifically for your device model. These ROM then also makes use of the available bootloader.

you have fastboot, so you have bootloader. try generic GSI
